How to recover files from corrupted Innodisk SATADOM D150SV
After 9 years of use, this 4GB SATADOM finally broke and wiped itself to the extent that the underlying Linux partitions are no longer visible.
While the device will show up as /dev/sdb, even testdisk cannot detect partitions.
When choosing an Intel/PC partition, I get the errors:
Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55

When choosing EFI partition, I get the error:
Bad GPT partition, invalid signature.
Trying alternate GPT
Bad GPT partition, invalid signature.

Is there a way to recover any of the files, or preferably even mount it properly after fixing the superblock issues? Ideally I would like to extract a PostgreSQL databse. At the moment I made a backup with ddrescue, which detected 0 read errors, curiously enough.
MTBF: 4 million hours
Flash endurance: 100,000 program-erase cycles
I suspect the flash endurance has perhaps been compromised - the warranty is curiously only for 5 years.

You've a backup? That might be your best bet at this stage. Can ddrescue read anything of value, or is the device simply returning zeros for all reads?

It claims "100% rescued". photorec isn't even able to recover individual files ... I guess when the flash memory goes , every single cell collapses at once?

@Cheetaiean Did you try the new version of testdisk 7.2 from February 2024, because there is a line for General Improvements Add support for BeFS for EFI GPT and Mac partition table, https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_7.2_Release#Improvements.

"It claims "100% rescued"" - that just means ddrescue encountered no read errors. It doesn't care about the data as long as it could read it. So if the disk is (now) returning only zeros for all reads you'll have a perfect image comprised entirely of zeros. You need to look at the image to see if there is any data there. (hexdump or a variant, od, or even strings might be starting points to see if there's data.)

hexdump shows lots of data, plenty of data.

Use a Digital Forensics Tool, e.g. Autopsy or Sleutihkit. https://www.sleuthkit.org

Absent a file recovery service (pricey, for reputable ones that achieve results), and absent any forensics tools, you could try re-creating the partition table on a copy of the disk image file that you recovered.  First, decide whether to use MSDOS or GPT partition type.  Next, recreate a partition definition, which is easier to figure out if there was only one partition on the failed disk.  Last, try running the appropriate filesystem checker (ie. for ext2/ext3/ext4/xfs/etc.).

"curiously only 5 years": uff, you're expecting much from a lower-end device (9 years ago, a 4 GB USB stick was already so low end that you'd get it as free gift with advertisement materials, and wouldn't have to thank the gifter overly much); that's a lot of warranty for something the flash memory manufacturer probably makes a very low margin on, no matter what the SSD built from it costs. But 100,000 program-erase cycles sounds like you might easily have exceeded if you used that SSD regularly. Assuming that SSD was in use 24/7 for 9 years, that amounts to a single erase/update every 50min

even assuming perfect wear levelling, after you've written 4 GB to it the first time, every write to a is a program/erase cycle. So, yeah, in all likelihood, you wrote that poor memory device to pieces, and now there's sufficient corruption in the partition table for reading it to fail.

You've confirmed that ddrescue has successfully copied the full disk as an image ("It claims "100% rescued"" and "hexdump shows lots of data, plenty of data").
On that basis I would clone the saved disk image:
cat disk.img >diskcopy.img    # might need `sudo`. Don't bother using `dd` here

and attempt to create a suitable disk partition on that copy. The new partition table will replace the ones that appear to have been lost.
You say that you know the partition offsets and they're at sector 2048 and 1949696, so you can simply re-create them. (Before you do that it might be worth running testdisk if you have it, to see if it can access a valid backup partition table. But see how it goes.)
parted diskcopy.img

  mklabel gpt
  unit s
  mkpart primary 2048 1949695
  mkpart primary 1949696 100%
  print
  quit

Otherwise, there are tools such as testdisk that will scan the disk (image) and attempt to identify possible partition starting points:
testdisk diskcopy.img

Permissions on diskcopy.img notwithstanding you shouldn't need to run either of these approaches as root.
Once you've recreated the partition table you can try a couple of loopback mounts:
lo=$(sudo losetup --find --show --partscan diskcopy.img )
ls "$lo"*

You should have three devices: the base /dev/loopN (for a numeric value of N) and its subsidiary /dev/loopNp1 and /dev/loopNp2. You can then mount these directly:
mkdir -p /mnt/p1 /mnt/n2
sudo mount -o ro /dev/loopNp1 /mnt/p1
sudo mount -o ro /dev/loopNp2 /mnt/p2


The disk has two partitions. Judging from an fdisk -l for an analogous img made at the same time, partition one starts at sector 2048, and partition two at 1949696

That's superb. In that case create a new partition table on the extra image copy with those two partitions. I'll update the answer accordingly

@Cheetaiean more detail added for you

So after making these partitions unfortunately no filesystems are recognized. I would assume they would be ext4, being a Debian system from 2015. I tried creating a new filesystem using mkfs -t ext4 but that wouldn't (and didn't) restore anything but wrote over existing data.

Creating a new filesystem was a bad idea! However, since you're working with a copy of the copy, recreate it and try with testdisk this time
